# NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, python-3.8, django-3.1

I'm new to using Django and I'm trying to write test for my pages app but I keep on getting the same error when testing for the homepage url name

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import HomePageView

app_name = 'pages'

urlpatterns = [
     path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

test.py

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class HomePageTest(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_homepage_url(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_homepage_name(self):
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_homepage_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
```

pages/home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
  Welcome
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify, but I assume it's `test_homepage_name` that is giving the error?

Try including the app name:

```
url = reverse('pages:home')
```